# Combinatorics: Is it true to say $s \in F$ where $s \in S$ and $F$ is a set of subsets of $S$

Tags: combinatorics

From this problem: (from *Measure Theory* by Paul R. Halmos, Springer-Verlag, 1950)

> Let $S$ be a set. Suppose that $s$ is an element of $S$, $T$ is a subset of $S$, and $F$ is a set of subsets of $S$. How many statements of the form $X R Y$ are possible, where $X$ and $Y$ are each taken from $\{S, s, T, F\}$ and $R$ is taken from $\{\in, \subseteq\}$? Classify each statement as always true, possibly true, or always false.

Is it true to say: $ s \in F $?

Ex: $S = \{1,2,3\}, s = 1,$ and $F = \{\{1\}, \{2,3\}\}$.

I'm thinking that it isn't true because: $1 \neq \{1\}$. Can anyone confirm?

EDIT: Thank you! I can continue with the problem now.

Comment: You are correct that these are different ideas. 1 is an element of your set $S$, whereas $\{1\}$ denotes the _set_ containing the element 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, indeed $s\notin F$ because $1\ne\{1\}$ (and $1\ne\{2,3\}$).
But with $S=\{\{1\},1,2\}$, $s=\{1\}$, $F=\{\{1\}\}$, you *do* have $s\in F$.